# Correct grammar form for two people owning the same object?

Tags: compound-possessives

Which is correct?
Paul's and Freda's Anniversary or Paul and Freda's Anniversary?

Comment: The Oxford Manual of Style recommends that the possessive 's is added only to the last item in a list when possession is shared. So it would be "Paul and Freda's Anniversary".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question or a variant thereof appears multiple times.